# Perl Popup_Menu Selection

Tags: perl, cgi

I try to popup_menu select with if/else. But it isn't work with if/else.

The Select for Workflow or Tasktyp change with differ lists.

**Workflow Group or Tasktyp for Type:**

```
my %datatype = (
    'workflow_group' => 'Workflow Group',
    'tasktype_group' => 'TaskType',
);
```

**Workflow Group or Tasktype for Value:**

```
my %workflow_group = (
    'one' => 'Contract',
    'two' => 'Exchange',
    'three' => 'Delivery',
    'four' => 'Event',
);

my %tasktype_group = (
    'one' => 'Contract',
    'two' => 'Router',
    'three' => 'DocSender',
    'four' => 'Transformer',
);
```

**Script with Variable (if/else):**

```
print "<TR>";
        print $lqcgi->td({-width=>'10%',},
        $lqcgi->h3('Type'),
        $lqcgi->popup_menu(-name=>'type',
                  -values=>[qw/workflow_group tasktype_group/],
                  -labels=>\%datatype,
                  -default=>'type_select'));

        my $types = $lqcgi->param('Workflow Group');

        print "<TD><h3>Value</h3>";
        if ($types){
        print $lqcgi->popup_menu(-name=>'value',
                  -values=>[qw/one two three four/],
                  -labels=>\%workflow_group,
                  -default=>'workflow'),
        $lqcgi->submit(-type => 'tasktype_start_command', -value => 'Start', -onclick => 'javascript:()'),
        $lqcgi->submit(-type => 'tasktype_stop_command', -value => 'Stop', -onclick => 'javascript:()');
        }
        else{
        print $lqcgi->popup_menu(-name=>'value',
                  -values=>[qw/one two three four/],
                  -labels=>\%tasktype_group,
                  -default=>'tasktype'),
        $lqcgi->submit(-type => 'tasktype_start_command', -value => 'Start', -onclick => 'javascript:()'),
        $lqcgi->submit(-type => 'tasktype_stop_command', -value => 'Stop', -onclick => 'javascript:()');
        }
print "</TD></TR>";
```

Notice: `foreach my $type(@types)`, `if (exists $types{$type})`, `if (defined $types{$type}`isn't working! Thank for your help!

**Here is find wrong:**

[image]

Comment: There are a couple of issues with your code. I don't fully understand what you are trying to do. `@types eq 'Workflow Group'` doesn't do what you think. It evaluates `@types` in scalar context, so it becomes `1` if there is one element in that array. And `1 eq 'Workflow Group'` is false.

Comment: @simbabque if I take at `Workflow Group` for `%dataworkflow_group` in lists or `Tasktype` for `%tasktype_group` in lists. `1 eq 'Workflow Group'` isn't working. I try `if (exists  $types{$type})` or`if (unfined $types{$type})` , but that're also both not working.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and fix the typos in your code. There are semicolons and commas mixed up and it's not clear if that is part of the problem, or simply an error when copy/pasting here. Show your _real code_.

Comment: @simbabque Ok. My Edit is finished. I've this little correct and another.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like your code is actually be working from a Perl/CGI perspective, but it may not be what you are expecting.  I have tested your code with both $types = "Workflow Group" (any defined value would work) and $types = "".

If $types is equal to anything, the %workflow_group popup is shown.  If $types is "" the %tasktype_group popup is shown.  So the if/else conditions are working.  And this leads me to conclude that your

```
  my $types = $lqcgi->param('Workflow Group');
```

has no value.  I am not sure whether you expect the $lqcgi->param('Workflow Group') value to be determined when the user chooses a value for the Type popup, and then automatically change the Value popup.  If that is the case, you would likely need to do modify the Value popup after the Type choice is made using something like Javascript.  Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah. You were right! I have to try Javascript. Javascript should good function. Thank you!